# How can I put my for-loop in dplyr::mutate( )? [tidyverse]

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a `for-loop` that corrects misspellings in strings (actually it changes closely spelled strings to be identical).

As I typically use `dplyr`'s functions and have long code sequences of many changes, I'd like to have a `dplyr`-friendly way to use my `for-loop` within a `mutate` call.

Here's an example.

```
name <-  c('pat','paet','Pat', 'bob',
     'beb','bab')
name
[1] "pat"  "paet" "Pat"  "bob"  "beb"  "bab"

for ( i in seq_along(name)){

  name <- ifelse(agrepl(name[[i]],name),name[[i]],name)

}

name
 [1] "pat" "pat" "pat" "bob" "bob" "bob"
```

I'd like to get the results above when using a `dplyr`/`data_frame` approach.

```
df <- data_frame(name_ii =  c('pat',
         'paet',
         'Pat',
         'bob',
         'beb',
         'bab'))
df %>% 
mutate(name = name_ii,
       name = for ( i in seq_along(name)){

  name <- ifelse(agrepl(name[[i]],name),name[[i]],name)

}
)

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: name_ii.
```

I've attempted to put it into a user-defined function called `identicator`.

```
identicator <- function(x){
name <- x

for ( i in seq_along(name)){

      name <- ifelse(agrepl(name[[i]],name),name[[i]],name)

    }
}

  df %>% 
    mutate(new.name = identicator(x))

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `d` is of unsupported type NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to return 'name' in the function  and `df %>% 
    mutate(new.name = identicator(name_ii))`

Comment: OK .. answer aside. This function doesn't "correct misspellings" it sets all subsequent approx matches to the spelling of the first instance. Try it with : `name <-  c('paet','bab','Pat', 'bob', 'beb','pat')`

Comment: @Stephen Henderson, I state that in the first sentence  . . 'actually it changes closely spelled strings to be identical.'

Comment: No not that either. Try `agrepl("bana", "ba"); agrepl("ba", "bana")` . Sorry I don't mean to be a pedant. I'm just not sure it's what you intend.

Comment: It does what I need for my data. I've got many rows of people's names in a dialect of Swahili. The average length is about 25 characters, and the data has been entered by several different people. I'm using this as a final test - after comparing similar name's genders, ages and other indicator variables.

I've actually been working on this for a while and this is my most recent approach. I'd greatly appreciate any tips/ideas if you have any? Cheers, E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with the `identicator` is that after assigning within the `for` loop, the 'name' is not returned

```
identicator <- function(x){
 name <- x

 for ( i in seq_along(name)){

     name <- ifelse(agrepl(name[[i]],name),name[[i]],name)

     }
   name  ###
 }
```

and the second issue is the function argument is 'name_ii' column

```
df %>% 
   mutate(new.name = identicator(name_ii))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  name_ii new.name
#  <chr>   <chr>   
#1 pat     pat     
#2 paet    pat     
#3 Pat     pat     
#4 bob     bob     
#5 beb     bob     
#6 bab     bob
```